# vuejs + firebase data push

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

Component code:

```
  let booksRef = db.ref().child('books')
  export default {
    name: 'google-map',
    firebase: function () {
      return {
        books: booksRef
      }
    },
    data: function () {
      return {
        markerCoordinates: [],
        markers: []
      }
    },
    created: function () {
      booksRef.on('value', snap => {
        snap.forEach(childSnap => {
          var childVal = childSnap.val();
           this.markerCoordinates = childVal.position;
        });
      });

    },
    mounted: function () {
      const element = document.getElementById(this.mapName)
      const mapCentre = this.markerCoordinates[0]
      const options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(mapCentre.latitude, mapCentre.longitude)
      }
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(element, options);
      this.markerCoordinates.forEach((coord) => {
        const position = new google.maps.LatLng(coord.latitude, coord.longitude);
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position,
          map: this.map
        });
        this.markers.push(marker)
      });
    }
  };
```

error capture :

[image]

I want to expose markers stored in firebase
Why does not the markerCoordinates contain data?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you establish a connection to listen on values for your collection, and at the moment you try to access the `this.markerCoordinates` it is empty (so this error is because the lifecycle and asynchronous handling). There are some solutions here:

1. Move your Firebase listener (`created` hook) to the on `mounted` hook and then call the code you have in the `mounted` lifecycle hook (you can create a separate method for this and call it once `this.markerCoordinates` is not empty)
2. I see you are using [Vuefire](https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire) bindings, you should stick to how the structure is suggested there

Comment: could not understand
I need a rough source